# Pandas assignment and copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If we run the following code,

```
def f(df):
    df = df.assign(b = 1)
    df["a"] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
f(df)
print(df)
```

We get

```
           0
0   1.298967
1  -0.887922
2   1.913559
3  -0.082032
4  -0.466594
..       ...
95 -0.845137
96  0.628542
97 -0.588897
98  0.464374
99  0.267946
```

Whereas, if we run the following,

```
def f(df):
    df = df
    df["a"] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
f(df)
print(df)
```

We get

```
           0  a
0  -0.510875  1
1   0.401580  1
2  -0.037484  1
3  -0.935115  1
4  -1.108471  1
..       ... ..
95  0.362075  1
96 -1.017991  1
97  1.881081  1
98  0.376828  1
99  0.771661  1
```

I know there's a concept of pass by object reference in python. Why don't the `df` in the second code gets copied? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first function:

```
def f(df):
    df = df.assign(b = 1)
    df["a"] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
f(df)
print(df) #doesnot return the changed columns
```

You are changing the input to a `.copy()` version of the input , as [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) returns a copy of the actual dataframe , from the docs:

> Returns a new object with all original columns in addition to new ones. Existing columns that are re-assigned will be overwritten.

To return the changes you make in the copy , you should return the copy:

```
def f(df):
    df = df.assign(b = 1)
    df["a"] = 1
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
print(f(df))
```

On the contrary , for your second function , you are assigning the column a on the input parameter in place, hence when you print the dataframe , you can see the changes in the original df.

```
def f(df):
    df = df
    df["a"] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
f(df)
print(df)
```

To achieve a similar behaviour to the first function try assigning `df = df.copy()`

```
def f(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df["a"] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
f(df)
print(df) # doesnot return the a column
```

Same as we did for function 1 , you should return the copy :

```
def f(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df["a"] = 1
    return df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1))
print(f(df)) #returns the column a
```

Hope this answers your question.